# Use a Vue service outside of a Vue component

Tags: axios, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, primevue, vue-options-api

I'm currently working on a vue 3 app using primevue 3.46. I'm wondering if it possible to use the ToastService to display a toast outside of a vue component.

Here is an example. I created an Axios instance so that i can intercept request and response errors. I would like to display a Toast if the status code is 401 (Unauthorized) or 403 (Forbidden). Tha fact that my axios interceptor is outside a vue component make it impossible to use the toast service because it provides a method for the Composition or the Option API.

Here is my `main.ts` file

```
// Core
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "@/App.vue";

// Styles
import "primevue/resources/themes/lara-dark-blue/theme.css";
import "primeflex/primeflex.css";
import "primeicons/primeicons.css";

// Plugins
import PrimeVue from "primevue/config";
import ToastService from "primevue/toastservice";

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(PrimeVue, { ripple: true });
app.use(ToastService);

app.mount("#app");
```

Here is my `plugin/axios.ts` file

```
import axios, { AxiosError } from "axios";

import { useToast } from "primevue/usetoast";

// Set default axios parameters
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL,
});

instance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => response,
    (error: AxiosError) => {
        const toast = useToast(); // The error seems to be here
        if (error.response?.status === 401) {
            toast.add({ summary: "Unauthenticated", severity: "error" });
        } else if (error.response?.status === 403) {
            toast.add({ summary: "Forbidden", severity: "error" });
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    }
);

export default instance;
```

The problem is that is always returns a vue error : `[Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.`

Is there any way to use the ToastService outside a vue component like in an axios interceptor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `useToast()` (or any other composable function) inside the `setup` function of a Vue component (or inside its `<script setup>`, which is the same thing), or inside another composable function (because it has the same context limitation).

But you can use a store (e.g: a reactive object, a pinia store, etc...) to trigger a change from the interceptor and then `watch` this change from a component responsible for rendering the alerts.

Generic example:

**toastStore.ts**

```
import { reactive, watch } from 'vue'

export const toastStore = reactive({
  toasts: []
})

// wrap this as composable, so you don't clutter the rendering component 
export const useToastStore = () => {
  const toast = useToast()
  watch(
    () => toastStore.toasts,
    (toasts) => {
      toasts.length && toast.add(toasts[toasts.length - 1])
    }
  )
}
```

**axios.ts**

```
import { toastStore } from './path/to/toastStore'
//...

instance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  (error: AxiosError) => {
    if (error.response?.status === 401) {
      toastStore.toasts.push({ summary: 'Unauthenticated', severity: 'error' })
    } else if (error.response?.status === 403) {
      toastStore.toasts.push({ summary: 'Forbidden', severity: 'error' })
    }
  }
)
```

**App.vue** <sup>***1***</sup>:

```
import { useToastStore } from './path/to/toastStore'
export default {
  setup() {
    useToastStore()
    // rest of your App.vue's setup function...
  }
  // rest of your App.vue's component definition... 
}
```

If you use `<script setup>` in `App.vue` just place the call to `useToastStore()` inside the setup script.

The above uses a rather basic reactive object as store. If you already have a store in your app, you can use its state to store the toasts array. ***<sup>2</sup>***

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - You don't have to place it in `App.vue`, you can use any other component, as long as its mounted when you push toasts to the store, so they get rendered.
***<sup>2</sup>*** - Note the code above will only show toasts pushed to the store while the rendering component (the one calling `useToastStore`) is mounted.
If you want a different behavior, you need to track which toasts have been shown to the user and which haven't, so you don't render the same toast more than once. That's why I suggested calling `useToastStore` in `App.vue`.